# NPGSQL: Relate Operation called with a LWGEOMCOLLECTION type

Tags: c#, postgis, npgsql

I have a query which fetches PostGIS data using Npgsql. Its purpose is to take a point (x,y co-ordinates) and work out which (if any) geometry is at that point. For the vast majority of geometries in the database the query works fine, but for at least one I get the following exception:

> ERROR: XX000: Relate Operation called with a LWGEOMCOLLECTION type. 
>   This is unsupported.

with the top of the stack trace being:

> [NpgsqlException (0x80004005): ERROR: XX000: Relate Operation called
>   with a LWGEOMCOLLECTION type.  This is unsupported.]
>   Npgsql.d__0.MoveNext() +3160
>   Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject(Boolean cleanup)
>   +808    Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRow(Boolean clearPending) +308    Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.Read() +47

All geometries should be valid as I call `ST_MakeValid` on any which aren't and there are currently none where `ST_IsValid` returns false. The geometry was created by calling `ST_GeomFromKML` and is rendered fine on a map as a raster layer using WMS via GeoServer or as a vector layer using `ST_AsGeoJSON` so the PostGIS data seems to be OK.

Is there any way I can amend my code or data to stop this happening? The part of the code failing is the part where the reader is being read in:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT area_code FROM area WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(:x, :y), 4326), shape) AND area_type_code = :typecode";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
var typeCodeParameter = new NpgsqlParameter
{
    DbType = DbType.String,
    ParameterName = "typecode",
    Value = _typeCode
};
var xParameter = new NpgsqlParameter
{
    DbType = DbType.Double,
    ParameterName = "x",
    Value = _x
};
var yParameter = new NpgsqlParameter
{
    DbType = DbType.Double,
    ParameterName = "y",
    Value = _y
};
command.Parameters.Add(typeCodeParameter);
command.Parameters.Add(xParameter);
command.Parameters.Add(yParameter);
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
        area = new AreaBasic
        {
            Code = (string)reader["area_code"]
        };
}
```

**EDIT:** further information. The same error occurs when running the query with hard coded values in pgAdmin III so the problem isn't Npgsql specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to trying to call an intersects or contains type query on a Geometry Collection, ie, where you have some mixture of points, lines and polygons (possibly multi).

There are, at least, a couple of possible fixes. The first one is simpler, but seems a bit hacky, which is simply to buffer your input geometry first by 0, which will result in non-polygons from being removed, so, in your case, simply changing your command.commandText to

```
SELECT area_code FROM area WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(:x, :y), 4326), 
ST_Buffer(shape, 0)) AND area_type_code = :typecode";
```

Note, this approach can often be used to fix invalid geometries, ones with self-intersecting loops and the like.

The second approach is to use [ST_Dump](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) on your shape field to split into individual geometries and then only use Polygons in the actual query by means of the [ST_GeometryType](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html) function.

```
SELECT area_code 
FROM 
  (SELECT area_code, (ST_Dump(area)).geom FROM area) poly  
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(:x, :y), 4326), poly.geom) 
AND ST_GeometryType(poly.geom) = 'ST_Polygon' 
OR ST_GeometryType(poly.geom) = 'ST_MultiPolygon'
AND area_type_code = :typecode";
```

This is untested, as I can't test this on you data clearly, but these approaches work in practice.